# A simple directive to show name of user not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have made a simple example of custom directive to show name of a person. It still is not showing it. Can someone help?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
    <person></person> 
<script>
    //module declaration
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    //controller declaration
    app.controller('myCtrl',function(){
        $scope.name = "Peter";
    });
    //directive declaration
    app.directive('person',function(){
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>' {{ name }} '</div>' 
       };
    });
</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use proper Javascript syntax. I'm talking about string concatenation (which you don't need). You also forgot to inject `$scope` into controller. Correct syntax:

```js
// module declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

// controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Peter";
});

// directive declaration
app.directive('person', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div>{{name}}</div>'
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <person></person>
</div>
```

Above will work for you, but this is just simple syntax stuff. More importantly is that you **should not** write such kind of directives, simply because they don't add real value. You could have just written `{{name}}` in template without directive at all.

Now *useful* directive would look something like this:

```js
// module declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

// controller declaration
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.user = {
    name: "Peter",
    age: 12,
    hobby: "Coding, reading"
  };
});

// directive declaration
app.directive('person', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      data: '='
    },
    template: 
      '<div>{{data.name}}, {{data.age}}</div>' +
      '<small>{{data.hobby}}</small>'
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <person data="user"></person>
</div>
```

In the above example, you isolate scope of the directive (so it becomes an UI component), making it truly reusable and flexible. Prefer this approach.

Comment: Very nice explaination!

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

- you don't inject $scope in the controller
- The template is wrong

Working code snippet:

```js
    //1 Module declaration
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    //controller declaration
    app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
        $scope.name = "Peter";
    });

//directive declaration
    app.directive('person',function(){
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>{{ name }}</div>' 
       };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
    <person>{{name}}</person>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

index.html

```
    <html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
    <person></person> 

</body> 
</html>
```

app.js

```
  //module declaration
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
  //controller declaration & inject $scope
  app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
      $scope.name = "Peter";
  });

  //directive declaration
  app.directive('person',function(){
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
      template: "<div> {{ name }}</div>" 
      };
  });
```